# error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm reading the Functional Programming in Scala book, on one of their exercises I got two compilation errors which I don't understand why I'm getting those.
I'm getting the following two errors on the code below:

```
error: value toList is not a member of Chapter5.Stream[Int]
    val list : List[Int] = st.toList
                              ^
Stream.scala:22: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Chapter5.Cons[A]
 required: Chapter5.Stream.type
    case Cons(h,t) => h() :: t().toList
         ^
two errors found
```

This is the trait and the companion object:

```
package Chapter5

sealed trait Stream[+A]

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h : () => A, t : () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream{
  def cons[A](hd : => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] = {
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }

  def toList[A]: List[A] = this match{
    case Cons(h,t) => h() :: t().toList
    case _ => List()
  }

}
```

When I try to call toList the following way I also get an error:

```
package Chapter5

object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    val arr = Array(1,3,4,6)
    val st : Stream[Int] = Stream.apply(arr : _*)
    val list : List[Int] = st.toList
  }
}
```

I don't understand these errors at all, for the first case: Obviously I define a toList method on the object. For the second Cons extends the Stream trait, so I don't understand why I cannot use pattern matching like this.

Comment: You're defining the methods inside the companion object and matching `toList` on `this`, which is `Stream.type` of the companion. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining these methods in `object Stream`, not the `trait Stream`. **The companion object of a type is** (almost) **completely unrelated to the type itself**. The only things that relate a companion object with its type are:

1. They happen to have the same name. (Technically, the names are in different namespaces (type vs. term), so this is just superficial.)
2. They can see each other's `private` parts. (This may be made stricter by declaring things `private[this]`.)

Therefore, `this` on line 21 does not mean "the `Stream` on which we are operating", it means "this singleton object, called `Stream`, which is almost unrelated to the trait, also called `Stream`." Similarly, on line 22, `Stream` doesn't have a `toList` method; it's `Stream.type` (the type of the companion) that does.

Either modify `toList` to take a stream parameter:

```
object Stream
  def toList[E](stream: Stream[E]): List[E] = stream match {
    //         !^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^!            ^!!!!^
  }
}
```

or move `toList` (and probably `cons`) into `trait Stream`:

```
sealed trait Stream[+E] {
  def cons(hd: => E) = ???
  def toList: List[E] = ???
}
```